# MVC Syncfusion Grid - HTML EJ Grid - Get Primary Key of Selected Row in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

Below is my grid code, how do I get the Primary Key Value when the cell is clicked in jquery?

I have tried searching online and can't find a working example.  Is there another way to get the value without using jquery or javascript?

```
<div id="CampaignGrid">
@(Html.EJ().Grid.Test.Test>("Grid")
...     
})
.Columns(col =>
{
    col.Field("iCampaign").HeaderText("Campaign").IsPrimaryKey(true).TextAlign(TextAlign.Left).Width(50).AllowEditing(false).Add();
    col.Field("vCampaignName").HeaderText("Campaign Name").IsPrimaryKey(false).TextAlign(TextAlign.Left).Width(260).AllowEditing(false).Add();                       
})
```

Answer (score 0):

when you are setting fields like `col.Field("iCampaign")`, you determine a tag with attribute name="iCampaign",which will be used in model binding.

so you can use a jquery selector like this :

```
$('[name = "iCampaign"]')
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also solve your problem this way :

```
 @(Html.EJ().Grid<EmployeeView>("MasterGrid")
    .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource1)
    .SelectedRowIndex(0)      
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Field("EmployeeID").HeaderText("Employee ID").IsPrimaryKey(true).TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(125).Add();
        col.Field("FirstName").HeaderText("First Name").Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("LastName").HeaderText("Last Name").Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("Title").HeaderText("Title").Width(150).Add();
        col.Field("BirthDate").HeaderText("Birth Date").TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Add();
        col.Field("Country").Width(100).HeaderText("Country").Add();

    })
    .ClientSideEvents(eve => { eve.RowSelected("rowSelected"); })
    )

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {           
        window.rowSelected = function (args) {
            var employeeID = args.data.EmployeeID;
            var detaildata = ej.DataManager(window.gridData).executeLocal(ej.Query().where("EmployeeID", ej.FilterOperators.equal, employeeID, false).take(10));
            var gridObj = $("#DetailGrid").ejGrid("instance");
            gridObj.model.dataSource = ej.DataManager(detaildata.slice(0, 5));
            $("#DetailGrid").ejGrid("refreshContent");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@(Html.EJ().Grid<EmployeeView>("MasterGrid")
    .Datasource((IEnumerable<object>)ViewBag.datasource1)
    .SelectedRowIndex(0)      
    .Columns(col =>
    {
        col.Field("EmployeeID").HeaderText("Employee ID").IsPrimaryKey(true).TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(125).Add();
        col.Field("FirstName").HeaderText("First Name").Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("LastName").HeaderText("Last Name").Width(100).Add();
        col.Field("Title").HeaderText("Title").Width(150).Add();
        col.Field("BirthDate").HeaderText("Birth Date").TextAlign(TextAlign.Right).Width(100).Format("{0:MM/dd/yyyy}").Add();
        col.Field("Country").Width(100).HeaderText("Country").Add();

    })
    .ClientSideEvents(eve => { eve.CellEdit("cellEdit"); })
    )

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function cellEdit(args)
      {
         var pkName = args.primaryKey[0];
         var pkValue = args.rowData[pkName];
      }
     </script>
```